# Unable to restore a class from file (C++)

Tags: c++, object, fstream

I have a list of object (of type class Radio_Data), that I need to be able to store to a file and restore from the file. I am saving classes in a binary file with this code:

```
for (listIter = listCont.begin(); listIter != listCont.end(); listIter++)
{
    file.seekg(iter * sizeof(Radio_Data), ios::beg);
    file.write((char *)&listIter, sizeof(Radio_Data));
}
```

and trying to restore them with this code:

```
for(counter = 0; counter < (fileSize/sizePerEntry); counter++)
    {
        file.seekg((counter) * sizeof(Radio_Data), ios::beg);
        file.read((char *)&station, sizeof(Radio_Data));
    }
```

I can see the information entered in a file, so I know saving works well. However, when trying to read back the info from file, incorrect data is shown. What am I doing wrong?

```
class Radio_Data
{
private:
    char name[21];      
    char callsign[5];   
    char band[3];
    char frequency[6];  
    char type[21];
    char city[21];
    char phone[11];     
    char website[41];

public:

    Radio_Data();
    ~Radio_Data(){};
    //More public methods
}
```

Here's what the save file looks like:
    0—F     x—F the hawk ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌCKDK FM 1039 Ìrock ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌWoodstock 
    ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ5198608520 www.thehawk.ca ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ
(There is^ a TAB character b-n 0-F and x-F)

This file should resolve itself to:

```
char name[21] == "the hawk";
char callsign[5] == "CKDK";
char band[3] == "FM";   
char frequency[6] == "1039";    
char type[21] == "rock";        
char city[21] == "Woodstock";       
char phone[11] == "5198608520";     
char website[41] == "www.thehawk.ca";
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That isn't the real code, so it's hard to guess what the real problem is.

Comment: There is no reading or writing in your code, only moving the current file position around.

Comment: Sorry: Added the 2 missing lines. There are about 3K lines of code in the project, so I only tried to enter the relevant ones.

Comment: A list iter is a what, a pointer? and you multiply it? really?+

Comment: The listIter is declared as such:  std::list <Radio_Data>::iterator listIter; This amounts to an unsigned integer.

Answer (score 2):

Tried the following (quick and dirty) code on Visual Studio 2012 *and* OpenBSD g++ version 4.2.1 and it worked...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

class Radio_Data
{
public:
    char name[21];      
    char callsign[5];   
    char band[3];
    char frequency[6];  
    char type[21];
    char city[21];
    char phone[11];     
    char website[41];

public:

    Radio_Data() {}
    ~Radio_Data(){}
    //More public methods
};

void set(Radio_Data* obj)
{
    strcpy(obj->name, "the hawk");
    strcpy(obj->callsign, "CKDK");
    strcpy(obj->band, "FM");
    strcpy(obj->frequency, "1039");
    strcpy(obj->type, "rock");
    strcpy(obj->city, "Woodstock");
    strcpy(obj->phone, "5198608520");
    strcpy(obj->website, "www.thehawk.ca");
}

void clear(Radio_Data* obj)
{
    memset(obj->name, 0, sizeof(obj->name));
    memset(obj->callsign, 0, sizeof(obj->callsign));
    memset(obj->band, 0, sizeof(obj->band));
    memset(obj->frequency, 0, sizeof(obj->frequency));
    memset(obj->type, 0, sizeof(obj->type));
    memset(obj->city, 0, sizeof(obj->city));
    memset(obj->phone, 0, sizeof(obj->phone));
    memset(obj->website, 0, sizeof(obj->website));
}

void prnt(Radio_Data* obj)
{
    std::cout << "---start object---" << std::endl;
    std::cout << obj->name << std::endl;
    std::cout << obj->callsign << std::endl;
    std::cout << obj->band << std::endl;
    std::cout << obj->frequency << std::endl;
    std::cout << obj->type << std::endl;
    std::cout << obj->city << std::endl;
    std::cout << obj->phone << std::endl;
    std::cout << obj->website << std::endl;
    std::cout << "----end object----" << std::endl;
}

void write(Radio_Data* obj)
{
    std::ofstream o("file.txt");
    o.write((char*)obj, sizeof(Radio_Data));
    o.close();
}

void read(Radio_Data* obj)
{
    std::ifstream i("file.txt");
    i.read((char*)obj, sizeof(Radio_Data));
    i.close();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Radio_Data obj;
    clear(&obj);
    prnt(&obj);
    set(&obj);
    prnt(&obj);
    write(&obj);
    clear(&obj);
    prnt(&obj);
    read(&obj);
    prnt(&obj);
    return 0;
}
```

It had this output in the console for both:

```
---start object---








----end object----
---start object---
the hawk
CKDK
FM
1039
rock
Woodstock
5198608520
www.thehawk.ca
----end object----
---start object---








----end object----
---start object---
the hawk
CKDK
FM
1039
rock
Woodstock
5198608520
www.thehawk.ca
----end object----
```

And this was the file contents:

Windows:

`the hawk             CKDK FM 1039  rock                 Woodstock            5198608520 www.thehawk.ca`

and OpenBSD:

`the hawkCKDKFM1039rockWoodstock5198608520www.thehawk.ca`

So there seems to be something else awry in your code..

Comment: would that still work if the file objects were declared as fstream?
    std::fstream file;
    file.open("file.dat", ios::out | ios::binary); //Writing to
    file.open("file.dat", ios::out | ios::binary); //Reading from

Comment: Are you writing an empty data set here as well as the filled-out one?

Comment: Yes, `std::fstream` with the `ios` flags will produce the same results. I'm not writing an empty data set in the code I posted, just printing it to the console for 'demonstration' purposes only. It fills the object, writes it to the file, clears it, prints it to show there's nothing in it, then reads the file 'into' the object and prints that (was trying to show it could be 'cleared' and 'read' from the file, sorry for that confusion).